# Getting all folders until the last level

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, io, asp.net-mvc-4, directory

I want to retreive all sub directories from a root directory until the last level.

I have ajusted my code but it only retrieve first level folders and the files inside it.

Is there a way to go all the way through the last level?

This is the code

```
    Response.Write("<ul class=\"jqueryFileTree\" style=\"display: none;\">\n");

    foreach (DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
    {
        if (drive.IsReady == true) 
        {
            Response.Write("\t<li class=\"drive collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive.ToString() + "\">" + drive.ToString() + "</a>\n");     

            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(drive.ToString());
            Response.Write("<ul>");

            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo di_child in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                Response.Write("\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive + di_child.Name + "/\">" + di_child.Name + "</a>\n");
                Response.Write("<ul>");

                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    string ext = "";

                    if (fi.Extension.Length > 1)
                    {
                        ext = fi.Extension.Substring(1).ToLower();
                    }

                    Response.Write("\t<li class=\"file ext_" + ext + "\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive + fi.Name + "\">" + fi.Name + "</a></li>\n");
                }

                Response.Write("</ul></li>");
            }
            Response.Write("</ul></li>");
       }
    }

    Response.Write("</ul>");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a recursive function.

```
private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetFilesByDirectory(string path)
{
    var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

    yield return new {path, directories, files };

    foreach(var directory in directories)
    {
        yield return GetFilesByDirectory(directory);
    }
}
```

and as a side note. you should not be calling Response.Write within the controller action. instead you can return an `ActionResult` for rendering a view and put your html template in the view.